# How do I connect to a samba share in nodejs using the smb2 module?

Tags: node.js

I cannot get this module to connect to my samba server using code similar to the example advised in the documentation:

```
// My Code...
// load the library

var SMB2 = require('smb2');

// create an SMB2 instance

 var smb2Client = new SMB2({share: "\\\\192.168.1.6\\media",
     domain: '',
     username: 'user_not_shown',
     password: 'real_passworn_not_shown',
     debug: true,
     autoCloseTimeout: 0
});


smb2Client.readdir('Docos\\SMB_Test\\Adult', function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error (readdir):\n", err);
        console.log("data", data);
    } else {
        console.log("Connection made.");
        console.log(data); 
    }
});
```

RESPONSE

> --request
>   fe534d42400000000000000000007e0000000000000000000000000000000000d2e24ba20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024000200010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002021002

Things I have tried:

1. Sending an email to the maintainer/author
2. Creating an issue in github

Please assist - especially from anyone using this module.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var SMB2 = require('smb2');

// create an SMB2 instance

 var smb2Client = new SMB2({share: "\\\\192.168.1.6\\media",
     domain: 'WORKGROUP',
     username: 'user_not_shown',
     password: 'real_passworn_not_shown',
     //debug: true,
     autoCloseTimeout: 0
});

smb2Client.readdir('Docos\\SMB_Test\\Adult', function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error (readdir):\n", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connection made.");
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
        smb2Client.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it would be great if you add some explanation to guide other users to understand your answer.

Answer (score -4):

smb2Client.readdir works for me using version "0.2.6" of this module. If directory is empty then `console.log(data);` on success should return empty list e.g. `[]`. Suggest checking SMB2 instance create.

Comment: this is not an answer